# Sorting with arsort on array not working (object)

Tags: php

I am trying to sort an object array with `arsort()` by value that is like:

```
1: "American"
2: "Mexican"
3: "Italian"
```

but for some reason it's not working. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I prepare the data with:

```
$list = '';
foreach ($res as $val) {    

    $list[$val['cuisine_id']] = $val['cuisine_name'];

}

arsort($list);
```

And when I return `return $list;` it's sorted descending by key, not be value.

The output of `$list` before `arsort($list)` is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => American
    [2] => Mexican
    [3] => Italian
)
```

I also tried `arsort($list, SORT_NATURAL);` but the same result.

Comment: You should create a SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($list)` before the sort, please?

Comment: Also, you mentioned object array, but you're using array syntax in the loop. What is the object you're referring to?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Updated with the output.

Comment: Okay. So you want it to be sorted in reverse alphabetical order by cuisine_name, and you're getting what looks like a ksort instead?

Comment: Yes, basically sorted by value, not key.

Comment: Using that data, it [works as expected for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e3d450cbbf8478950ad811e750becfd111a5051a).

Comment: Yes, same here. Is there any other code between the sort and the return that could be modifying it? It doesn't seem to be reproducible with what's shown here.

Comment: Not at all. Will keep trying to track down the problem and update when I have more. That's weird! Thank you anyways in the meantime for giving it a try :)

Comment: Weird indeed. Good luck!

Comment: @moomoo  As indicated by the first comment, you should be able to give us a snippet of code that we can copy/paste to run and reproduce your problem.  If you can't, it's a _lot_ harder for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible problems:
    - you initialized list with the string.
    - your Data Access Object returns something weird as the result

Made it work using:

```php
    <?php
    // example code

    $res = [
        [
            'cuisine_id' => '1',
            'cuisine_name' => 'American',
        ],
        [
            'cuisine_id' => '2',
            'cuisine_name' => 'Mexican',
        ],
        [
            'cuisine_id' => '3',
            'cuisine_name' => 'Italian',
        ],
    ];

    // Code you provided broke here.
    $list = [];
    foreach ($res as $val) {    
        $list[$val['cuisine_id']] = $val['cuisine_name'];
    }

    // changed to normal sorting (not reversed one)
    asort($list, SORT_REGULAR);

    var_dump($list);
    ?>
```